# Is there a way to send MultiPartFile and JSON together as request in Spring Boot REST Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I tried implementing this way, but I get `415 Error` if I send the request. I don't want to split it into two different request. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

```java
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @PostMapping(value = "/file/new",
            consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<DefaultResponseDto<Object>> createFile(HttpServletRequest servletRequest,
                                                                 @RequestBody @Valid
                                                                 PortfolioFileSaveRequestDto request,
                                                                 @RequestPart MultipartFile file) {
        List<String> tokenInfo = jwtProvider.authorizeJwt(servletRequest.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION));

        ...

        Portfolio portfolio = portfolioService.saveFile(request, user.getUsername(), profile, file);

        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a field for the `MultipartFile` in `PortfolioFileSaveRequestDto` so you can handle all the data together.

Comment: `PortfolioFileSaveRequestDto` in the case is JSON, so I don't think having `MultipartFile` in JSON would work... Am I wrong?

Comment: @gs97ahn If you make the request using [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), then it would work.

Comment: Thanks I fixed it by making into FormData